# Dynamically changing images in a div

Tags: javascript, image, html

I've five images and would like to display it in a same div one by one with interval of 2 sec. Can anyone please suggest any solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple javascript example:

```
var currentImage = 0;
var images = [
    'a.jpg',
    'b.jpg'
];
var imageElement = document.getElementById('yourImageTagId');

function nextImage(){
    currentImage = (currentImage + 1) % images.length;
    imageElement.src = images[currentImage];
}

var timeoutId = setTimeout(nextImage, 1000);
```

It expects you to have some html like this:

```
<img src="a.jpg" id="yourImageTagId" />
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it in JavaScript without using jQuery?

Comment: @Mayur: I've added an example on how to do it without jQuery. Do note that I haven't tested it so you might need to debug before it works ;)

Comment: nice example! Just remember that using a throughly tested library such as JQuery would allow you not only work faster but ensure that it works across different browsers.

Comment: @Helmut Granda: You are correct that jQuery is usually a better solution. However, code as simple as this will work just as well in all modern browsers.

Comment: @WoLpH. I agree with you but there are times when a solution is not good enough by just working on "modern browsers"

Answer (score 2):

[Jquery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) is really flexible... you could hook it up to whatever youve got already marked up pretty easily.

Comment: Is there any way to do it in JavaScript without using jQuery?

Comment: Sure, i mean jQuery is just a javascript library. Its just more time consuming and is bound to me be more prone to error. Im sure if you search for `javascript slideshow` you'll find some tutorials on implementing something similar but its not going to have the flexibility youll get out of the box with Cycle or something similar based on a different library like PrototypeJS.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this nowadays but one simple way is using the following jquery plugin:

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Here is a simple demo in action fading images one after the other.

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/basic.html

Comment: Is there any way to do it in JavaScript without using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout`

You can do something like this.

```
function selectData(currentIndex) {
    // select current's element "display" to "none" and show next element
    ...

    // schedule next change in two second        
    setTimeout("selectData(" + nextIndex + ");", 2000);
};
```

I assume all images are inside that div already and have style `display:none`